# ROS2: GPU LIDAR Selectively Interact with Objects in Gazebo

Tags: plugins, ros, gazebo-simu

Is it possible to have one of the lidar sensors from here: http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=sensor#link_sensor (preferably the gpu_lidar) interact selectively with objects in a Gazebo scene?
i.e. I'd like a LIDAR sensor to be able to only interact with objects/models of my choosing vs all in a scene.

If so, what are the option for doing so?
My internet search thus far has turned up mostly empty with a possible hint here: https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25156/how-to-make-ray-sensor-ignore-body-of-the-robot/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out after digging through https://github.com/gazebosim and its various repositories corresponding to the lidar sensor, that the [`visibility_mask`](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=sensor#camera_visibility_mask) element applies to the sensor type "gpu_lidar" as well as sensor type "camera" (the only sensor it is currently mentioned for on the SDF webpage) and will work for models in the world/sdf that have a visual element with its [`visibility_tag`](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=visual#visual_visibility_flags) set accordingly. This works on ros2 galactic.

So something like the following sensor definition in a urdf file will not see the SDF model defined below:

```
<gazebo reference="tool">
    <sensor type="gpu_lidar" name="gpu_lidar">
      <update_rate>40.0</update_rate> 
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <topic>sonar</topic>
      <visualize>1</visualize>
      <ignition_frame_id>left_tool</ignition_frame_id>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>15</samples>
            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.1309</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.1309</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>15</samples>
            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.1309</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.1309</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.02</min>
          <max>4.0</max>
        </range>
        <visibility_mask>4294967294</visibility_mask>
      </ray>
      <plugin filename="ignition-gazebo-sensors-system" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors">
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

Model SDF:

```
<model name='tower'>
    <pose>0.066472 2.94969 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <link name='cylinder_link'>
      <inertial>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.14580000000000001</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.14580000000000001</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.125</izz>
        </inertia>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='cylinder_collision'>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.5</radius>
            <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode/>
          </friction>
          <bounce/>
          <contact/>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name='cylinder_visual'>
        <visibility_flags>1</visibility_flags>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.5</radius>
            <length>1</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>1 1 1 1</specular>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
    </link>
    <static>false</static>
    <self_collide>false</self_collide>
  </model>
```